# Ajax call - Which button pressed?

Tags: html, ajax, button

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){ 
        txtname=$("#btn1").val();
        $.ajax({url:"doSome.php",data:{name:txtname},success: function(ajaxresult){
            $("#ajaxrequest").html(ajaxresult);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1" value="myButton">Click to send1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="myButton2">Click to send2</button>
<div id="ajaxrequest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I recognize which button pressed in line: $("#btn1").click(function(){
without having to write again the same code for btn2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector on all buttons and then get back the ID when clicked

```
$('button').click(function()
{
   alert( $(this).attr('id') ); // Button ID clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( '#btn1' ).click(function(){
     submitForm( 'btnOne' );
}); 

$( '#btn2' ).click(function(){
     submitForm( 'btnTwo' );
});
```

And then pass your parameter in a single function:

```
function submitForm( type ){

    var dataString = $('#form_confirm_delete').serialize();
    dataString += "&type=" + type; 
    $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "doSome.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,       
          success: (function(response) 
            {
                alert('Yes');
            })

     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, simply use multiple selectors:

```
$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function(e) {
    var btn1Clicked = $(this).is('#btn1'); 
    var btn2Clicked = $(this).is('#btn2'); 
});
```